# Xcode 11: Changes in code not updated to app or breakpoint doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode11

XCode: 11.1
OS: 10.15
Test device: iPhone 5s, iOS: 12.4.2

Hi guys,
I made a stupid mistake to immediately upgrade Xcode and MacOS, without waiting for a later stable version.

Anyway, if I made changes in my code, for example adding a NSLog() line, this addition is not updated on the app in my test device. To make it work, I have to uninstall the app from the test device, and reinstall it by running the code from Xcode.
This happens every time I make changes in code. I have to delete the app on the device and reinstall it again.

I was looking for a solution on the internet, but didn't find any.
I assume this is a Xcode bug, but I'm also curious if you have the same problem. If hope someone has a quick fix.

**Update 1**
On the simulator it works ok.

Comment: Have I understand you correctly, after you rebuild the application changes are not applied?

Comment: Have you tried to manually delete the application temporally build folders, DerivedData and Xcode caches?

Comment: @Igor no not yet, because I have to figure out where to delete them as I don't look at these folder often  (maybe once a year when doing certificates). But I'll try that.

Comment: yes, you should try that, it helps me with a most count of Xcode problems

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `Build System` to `Legacy`:

`File` > `Project Settings` > `Build System`

[image]

The new Build System has some problems with app cache.

Comment: `Legacy build system` is never a solution, it is just a transition. Sooner or later it wont work, and it will leave you with a lot of unresolved problems

Comment: This didn't work, as the app is still being cached.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, even changing something simple like a print would cause the breakpoints to stop working. I would have to reinstall the app on the test device every time I made a change for it to be reflected in the app. After I restarted the test phone, Xcode, and cleaned the build folder it worked for me.

Try to restart the test device, then run the app again. If this does not work:

- Navigate to ~/library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
- Remove the .mobileprovision file that corresponds to the app you are working on. (you have to click on the files to see what they are, otherwise its just a long string)
- Navigate to ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_APP_NAME
- Remove the build folder
- close Xcode, uninstall the app, restart the phone, open the Xcode project, clean the build folder, run the app

Comment: That solution doesn't stick as subsequent runs are still cached. It's simply easier to uninstall the app from the device each time, but all test data will be lost.